# Where do I put a return in a function?

Tags: swift, return-value

My code is returning 2 errors, both are unresolved identifiers. I looked up what means and most query answers are saying that I need to declare the constant first, but I have already done that.

I'm very new to coding and everytime I encountered this problem it was because I forgot to declare the constant or variable and I would catch my mistake but I'm stumped on this one.

```swift
var counter = 2

func fibonacci(_ x:Int ) -> Int {
    var a = 1
    var b = 1
    if counter < x {
        let sum = a + b
        a = b
        b = sum
        counter += 1


    }
    print(sum)
    return sum
}


fibonacci(5)
```

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_scope_and_lifetime

Comment: Can you share the exact errors that you are seeing?

Comment: matt, thanks for the link.

Comment: I should have pasted a screenshot instead of the code. That way the errors will show also. I was able to fix the error. My print (sum) and return sum should have been in the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

I bet you'll want to define `counter` within the scope of your function (passing it as a parameter might not make sense) and then define `sum` outside the scope of the `if` statement like this:

```
func fibonacci(_ x:Int ) -> Int {
    var a = 1
    var b = 1
    var sum = 0
    var counter = 0

    if counter < x {
        sum = a + b
        a = b
        b = sum
        counter += 1
    }
    print(sum)
    return sum
}
```

Comment: They did define `counter`; it was just eaten by StackOverflow's Markdown parser. I reformatted it using 4-spaces instead of 3-ticks

Comment: Oh. Gotcha. Good to know.

Comment: Use `while` loop instead of `if` condition

Answer (score 1):

You've declared the variable sum inside the `if` condition and using it outside the `if` condition.

Return `b` instead of `sum` at the end of the function. Your `if` block will be executed only once. You should use `while loop`

```
var counter = 2

func fibonacci(_ x:Int ) -> Int {
    var a = 1
    var b = 1
    while counter < x {
        let sum = a + b
        a = b
        b = sum
        counter += 1
    }
    print(b)
    return b
}

print(fibonacci(5))
```

You can simplify the swapping using a tuple

```
var counter = 2

func fibonacci(_ x:Int ) -> Int {
    var a = 1
    var b = 1
    while counter < x {
        (a,b) = (b,a+b)
        counter += 1
    }
    print(b)
    return b
}

print(fibonacci(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 2
func fibonacci(_ x:Int ) -> Int {
     var a = 1
     var b = 1
     var sum = 0 //this is when if you want to add sum
     //var counter = 0 if you may please work around the counter 
    if counter < x {
       sum = a + b
       a = b
       b = sum
       counter += 1
    }
    return sum //if you declare sum then return sum could be used
}
var x = fibonacci(5)//here the return value is stored or used for further computations
print(x) // the returned value can be printed in this way or directly print(fibonacci(5))
```

If you feel like learning it more please go through following link https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

The code above is not a solution to fibonacci series but a solution to your error. Fibonacci series can be solved in many ways using logic. As your question is only for the errors the program above solves it. If you feel like studying it using algorithms please checkout this link: https://www.codewithc.com/fibonacci-series-algorithm-flowchart/

I hope the answer helps!

Comment: sum is already in b so no sum is required for the program that @pangan919 has provided

Answer (score -1):

The unresolved indentifiers errors is because neither counter or sum are variables defined.

Just define them, Eg:

```
    var sum = 0;

    func fibonacci(counter: Int, x:Int) -> Int {
        var a = 1
        var b = 1

        if counter < x {
            sum = a + b;
            a = b
            b = sum

            return fibonacci(counter: counter + 1, x: x)
        }

        return sum
    }

    fibonacci(counter: 0, x: 5)
```

Note: the fibonacci func is not working properly but the identified errors were solved.

Comment: `counter` was defined. And why did you move `sum` outside of the function?

Comment: Use `while` loop instead of `if` condition